# Reset app or state in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm working with an app that was handed to us that is fairly big, and im very new to React Native.

I'm not sure that resetting will solve it. But I think I somehow polluted my state. Everything worked fine but then I wanted to reset my state, so I found this in `app.js`

```
componentWillMount() {
  let persistore = persistStore(store, null, () => {
    this.setState({rehydrated: true})
  });
  // persistore.purge();
}
```

So I uncommented `persistore.purge();`. But now when I try to start it I get:

Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'instanceInfo.pcb')

And it wont stop stageing. Any ideas on what I can try to do. To "reset" what I have done? I have already reseted to a stable commit in git.

Comment: why don't you dispatch action to reset state based on your condition?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question resetting state means the whole store i.e. app state?

If so then

```
const appReducer = combineReducers({
    nav,
    listReducer,
    movieDetail
});

const initialState = appReducer({}, {});

const rootReducer = (state, action) => {  
    if(action.type == "RESET_APP_STATE") {
        state = undefined
    }
    return appReducer(state, action);
}
```

If you want particular state i.e reducer state same thing but only for that particular reducer in `switch` mostly what we use, `return undefined`

Comment: I have react native app, i would like to know how reset particular state, not all state, I am usign Redux.